# Cannot rotate car and tilemap is not fully visible

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am trying to port the following Phaser2 example (https://phaser.io/examples/v2/tilemaps/fill-tiles) into Phaser3. I am experiencing two issues:

1. I cannot rotate the vehicle as the left/right keys will not work.

[image]

2. I cannot get the tilemap to display correctly, it seems cut off.

```
    import Phaser from "phaser";
    
    const config = {
      type: Phaser.AUTO,
      parent: "phaser-example",
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      physics: {
        default: 'arcade'
      },
      scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update,
        render: render
      }
    };
    
    const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
    let cursors;
    let player;
    let map;
    let speed = 0;
    
    function preload() {
      this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('desert', 'desert.json');
      this.load.image('tiles', 'https://examples.phaser.io/assets/tilemaps/tiles/tmw_desert_spacing.png')
      this.load.image('car', 'http://labs.phaser.io/assets/sprites/car90.png')
    }
    
    function create() {
      map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'desert' });
      const tiles = map.addTilesetImage('Desert', 'tiles');
      const layer = map.createDynamicLayer('Ground', tiles, 0, 0);
    
      cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
      player = this.physics.add.sprite(450, 80, 'car');
    
      this.cameras.main.startFollow(player, true, 0.05, 0.05);
    }
    
    function update() {
    
      // Drive forward if cursor up key is pressed down
    
      if (cursors.up.isDown && speed <= 400) {
        speed += 10;
      } else {
        if (speed >= 10) {
          speed -= 10
        }
      }
    
      // Drive backwards if cursor down key is pressed down
    
      if (cursors.down.isDown && speed >= -200) {
        speed -= 5;
      } else {
        if (speed <= -5) {
          speed += 5
        }
      }
    
      // Steer the car
    
      if (cursors.left.isDown) {
        player.body.angularVelocity = -5 * (speed / 1000);
      } else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        player.body.angularVelocity = 5 * (speed / 1000);
      } else {
        player.body.angularVelocity = 0;
      }
    
      player.body.velocity.x = speed * Math.cos((player.body.angle - 360) * 0.01745);
      player.body.velocity.y = speed * Math.sin((player.body.angle - 360) * 0.01745);
    }
    
    function render() {
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I loaded the code in a blank project without assets, and was able to see the image missing object rotate. However, it looks like the dependency of speed in angular rotation is too low. If you reduce the decrease in scaling of speed used for calculating angular velocity, you can get the car to turn more quickly.
Proof -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/phaser-2-example-so